# ExtJs rowediting insert new row error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'syncContent' of null

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

My rowediting work ok with Update grid row but grid gave to me error when try to add new row after click save.

NOTE:(when remove `renderer` from the combo box grid insert work ok. but that case to show ID in the combo grid column that why i added `renderer` function for combo)

error code

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'syncContent' of null
```

that error point to ext-all-debug.js file in bellow code for `oldCell` become null value

```
        cellSelector = me.getCellSelector(column);
        oldCell = Ext.DomQuery.selectNode(cellSelector, oldRowDom);
        newCell = Ext.DomQuery.selectNode(cellSelector, newRowDom);


        if (isEditing) {
            Ext.fly(oldCell).syncContent(newCell);
        }
```

this is how i add new row into the grid

```
var grid = grid;
var rowEditing = grid.getPlugin('RowEditor');
var store = grid.getStore();
var model = model;
rowEditing.cancelEdit();
store.insert(0, model);
var main_id     = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[itemId=txtmain_id]')[0].getValue();
store.data.items[0].data.CSTMR_ID = main_id;
rowEditing.startEdit(0, 0);
grid.getSelectionModel().select(0, true);
```

this grid edit combo field column

```
columns: [
   {
       xtype: 'gridcolumn',
       renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
           var store =store;
           var selrecord = store.getAt(store.findExact('ID', value));
           return selrecord.get('NAME');
       },
       itemId: 'colName',
       dataIndex: 'ID',
       text: 'Name',
       editor: {
           xtype: 'combobox',
           itemId: 'cboName',
           name: 'ID',
           displayField: 'NAME',
           store: store,
           valueField: 'ID'
       }
   },
```

store for the combo

```
   Ext.define('store', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store',

    requires: [
        'model',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],
```

Model for combo

```
constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'model',
        storeId: 'store',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'url?submit=true&action=getac',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
}
```

please help to me avoid that 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'syncContent' of null ' error for new row insert

Answer (score 3):

Had this exact problem and Vitale's response does work - after adding in the missing colon like so

```
return (index === -1) ? "" : store.getAt(index).get('NAME')
```

This makes sure that the renderer does not try and find the display value (the 'NAME') before rowedit has finished adding the record to the store (and saved an appropriate index), as the new record's index defaults to -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Probably problem in renderer.
Fix:

var index = store.findExact('ID', value);
return (index === -1) ? "" store.getAt(index).get('NAME');
```